# Displaying only video/image while python program running on background

Tags: python, hdmi, video, image, terminal

I have a Raspberry Pi 3B with a Python3 code running 24/7.

Right now, I'm running Raspbian Stretch desktop on console mode with no I/O. I only connect a screen via HDMI and an USB keyboard for debugging.

To make the code run automatically everytime I plug the Raspberry, I have this lines at the end of the file `/home/pi/.bashrc` (this makes the program run everytime you open a terminal, so this runs on foreground everytime I boot on console mode):

```
cd /MyCodePath
sudo python3 main.py
```

Now I want to connect an HDMI screen and I want it to display some image or video instead of displaying the output of my program.

I have seen someone using Kivy to do something kinda similar, but it seems too big and hard to learn (I think is not worth just to do what I want).

Is there an "easy" way to do this?

**EDIT 1**:
I tried calling omxplayer in infinite loop, but the problem is that everytime the video reachs its end and restarts, the console is seen for a second. I know how to make the console look just black (doing a `clear`, not having any Python output and changing the prompt color to black), but it still blinks everytime the video ends and starts again.

```
call_args = "omxplayer /video_path/my_video.mp4".split()
while True:
    subprocess.call(call_args)
```

I'll keep looking for better solutions, this isn't enough at all.

**EDIT 2:**
Okay so adding `--loop` to the omxplayer command works fine, but now I don't know how to stop it when I app closes naturally. I tried this but doesn't seem to work:

```
pkill omxplayer
killall omxplayer
```

Also the python3 code I'm using now to launch omxplayer is this one:

```
@staticmethod
def start_loop():
    path = "/video_path/my_video.mp4"
    omx = "omxplayer --no-osd -b -o local --loop "
    if os.path.isfile(path):
        os.system(omx + user_path + " &")
```